# How to compare two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables (`Original` and `Load`) and I want to compare them using a stored procedure.

The database is SQL Server 2008.

Here is my example SP:

```
USE [TestDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ValidateLoad] 
AS 
    SET nocount ON; 

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
              FROM   dbo.original 
              EXCEPT 
              SELECT * 
              FROM   dbo.LOAD) 
      BEGIN 
          PRINT 
      'Warning! The following information has not been loaded' 

       PRINT '---------------------------------' 

       PRINT 'Load result: Fail' 

          SELECT * 
          FROM   dbo.original 
          EXCEPT 
          SELECT * 
          FROM   dbo.LOAD 

      set noexec on
      END 

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
              FROM   dbo.LOAD 
              EXCEPT 
              SELECT * 
              FROM   dbo.original) 
      BEGIN 
          PRINT 
      'Warning! The following information does not exist in Original table' 

       PRINT '---------------------------------' 

       PRINT 'Load result: Fail' 

    SELECT * 
    FROM   dbo.LOAD 
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT * 
    FROM   dbo.original 

    set noexec on
END 

    PRINT 'Load result: Succeeded'
```

I find it not very efficient.

My intention is to validate that these two tables/datasets are identical, if not, output results with meaningful error messages.

Any thought?

Thank you.

Comment: Do the tables have key columns? Are there any combinations of columns that are unique?

Comment: Use this: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/

Comment: Hi Laurence, these two dataset does not have key columns, however the combination of all columns are unique.

Comment: Hi Norla, I can't use any other third party tool as I am not allowed to install any. It needs to be done in SQL.

Comment: If the contents of the two tables should always be identical, why are there two tables? Why is one not sufficient? Perhaps if you could explain that aspect more clearly...

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered comparing the two using a merge statement.

when not matched insert into #temp.  then you can display the results of your temp table.

Comment: From the looks of the syntax, [WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN] I don't seem to be able to insert them into a temp table? It looks like i will have to insert them into the source table?

Comment: My apologies.  I had a similar problem where I had to report the missing results from original.  I used the merge then output clause to insert into the temp table for reporting, but I also had to insert those missing records as well.  I'm sure the efficiency would go out the window if you inserted then removed those inserted rows.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have at least one column c1 that has a NOT NULL constraint, then this query should give you a list of all rows that are missing in either table:

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.* 
FROM dbo.original t1 full outer join dbo.LOAD t2
ON (list of join keys)
WHERE t1.c1 IS NULL or t2.c1 IS NULL
```

Not sure how efficient it is compared to your EXCEPT-based query though, you would need to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Answer in the general case:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
UNION 
SELECT * FROM tableB
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM tableA 
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM tableB;
```

---

Detailed answer:

Q. What do the letters SQL stand for? A. Scarcely Qualifies as a Language... ROFL but consider the following serious points:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
   ( ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, data_col VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL );

DECLARE @MyTable TABLE 
   ( ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, data_col VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL );
```

Now questions:

Q. In language (computer science) terms, is `@MyTable` a variable?
A. Well...

Problem 1: can't assign a table value to `@MyTable` e.g.

```
-- Assignment attempt 1:
SET @MyTable = MyTable;  -- COMPILE ERROR

-- Assignment attempt 2:
SET @MyTable = ( VALUES ( 1, NULL ), ( 2, '' ), ( 3, 'Test' ) );  -- COMPILE ERROR
```

Problem 2: can't compare variables e.g.

```
-- Comparison attempt 1:
IF ( @MyTable = @MyTable ) BEGIN; 
    PRINT 'Tables are the same.' 
END;  -- COMPILE ERROR

-- Comparison 2:
IF ( @MyTable = ( VALUES ( 1, NULL ), ( 2, '' ), ( 3, 'Test' ) ) ) BEGIN; 
    PRINT 'Tables are the same.' 
END;  -- COMPILE ERROR
```

...so we must believe that @MyTable is a 'variable' that support neither assignment nor comparison.

Q. If `@MyTable` is a variable, what in language (computer science) terms is `MyTable`?
 A. Constrant? Value? Type? Class? Struct? None of the above?

...Yes, SQL is a very strange language indeed!

Q. What is a relational operator?
 A. In the relational model, it is an operator that takes two relation values as arguments and returns a relation value as a result.

Q. Does SQL support relational operators?
 A. Not exactly. SQL does have operators that would be familiar a user of a truely relational language (`UNION`, `INTERSECT`, `EXCEPT`, etc). However, SQL supports non-relational features, most notably nulls, duplicate rows and duplicate column names. Therefore, great care is required to ensure the arguments to and results from these operators are equivalent to relations.

Q How to compare two tables for equality using SQL's 'relational-style' operators?
A Here's one way:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
UNION 
SELECT * FROM tableB
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM tableA 
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM tableB;
```

Test to demonstrate the above (noting the following are *not* all relation values but do prove the operators work logically with SQL nulls):

Example 1: tables are the same (expect zero rows == PASS):

```
WITH tableA AS
     ( SELECT * FROM ( VALUES ( 1, NULL ), 
                              ( 2, '' ), 
                              ( 3, 'Test' )
                     ) AS T ( ID, data_col ) ),
     tableB AS
     ( SELECT * FROM ( VALUES ( 1, NULL ), 
                              ( 2, '' ), 
                              ( 3, 'Test' )
                     ) AS T ( ID, data_col ) )
SELECT * FROM tableA
UNION 
SELECT * FROM tableB
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM tableA 
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM tableB;
```

Example 2: tableB is a proper subset of tableB (expect rows == FAIL):

```
WITH tableA AS
     ( SELECT * FROM ( VALUES ( 1, NULL ), 
                              ( 2, '' ), 
                              ( 3, 'Test' )
                     ) AS T ( ID, data_col ) ),
     tableB AS
     ( SELECT * FROM ( VALUES ( 1, NULL ), 
                              ( 2, '' ) 
                     ) AS T ( ID, data_col ) )
SELECT * FROM tableA
UNION 
SELECT * FROM tableB
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM tableA 
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM tableB;
```

Example 3: tableA is a proper subset of tableB (expect rows == FAIL):

```
WITH tableA AS
     ( SELECT * FROM ( VALUES ( 1, NULL ), 
                              ( 3, 'Test' )
                     ) AS T ( ID, data_col ) ),
     tableB AS
     ( SELECT * FROM ( VALUES ( 1, NULL ), 
                              ( 2, '' ), 
                              ( 3, 'Test' )
                     ) AS T ( ID, data_col ) )
SELECT * FROM tableA
UNION 
SELECT * FROM tableB
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM tableA 
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM tableB;
```

Example 4: tableA and tableB have some but not all row values in common (expect rows == FAIL):

```
WITH tableA AS
     ( SELECT * FROM ( VALUES ( 1, NULL ), 
                              ( 4, 'Lone' )
                     ) AS T ( ID, data_col ) ),
     tableB AS
     ( SELECT * FROM ( VALUES ( 1, NULL ), 
                              ( 4, 'Sole' )
                     ) AS T ( ID, data_col ) )
SELECT * FROM tableA
UNION 
SELECT * FROM tableB
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM tableA 
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM tableB;
```

Example 5: tableA and tableB have no row values in common (expect rows == FAIL):

```
WITH tableA AS
     ( SELECT * FROM ( VALUES ( 5, NULL ), 
                              ( 6, 'Different' )
                     ) AS T ( ID, data_col ) ),
     tableB AS
     ( SELECT * FROM ( VALUES ( 7, NULL ), 
                              ( 8, 'Not the same' )
                     ) AS T ( ID, data_col ) )
SELECT * FROM tableA
UNION 
SELECT * FROM tableB
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM tableA 
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM tableB;
```

Q. Why do SQL Server DBAs tend not to use this syntax and prefer, say, `FULL OUTER JOIN`?
A. Probably for a variety of reasons, such as familiarity with legacy syntax (e.g. `EXCEPT` was introduced in SQL Server 2005). But most likely is that a SQL DBA will tend to want to write what they feel will be the most efficient query (pejoratively, premature optimization). It is indeed true the SQL Server optimizer does not cope well with operators `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT`.

Q. Why prefer the 'relational-style' operators?
A. Because they are less verbose and arguably easier to read. Both of these are good qualities for test code.